# Set-Cookie working in Safari with localhost but not with server

Tags: go, cookies, server, safari, localhost

I am using React.js in the frontend and Golang API in the backend. Earlier when I tested with localhost development environment Set-Cookie was working fine with Safari but when I deployed my apps (frontend and backend running separately) on the servers for testing, the Set-Cookie is not working only with Safari. SSL certificates are not installed and I am just using the IP address for accessing the website and API. When I checked the console I saw that cookie is being issued successfully and received by Safari but it is not storing it.

Below is cookie configuration

```
jwtCookie := &http.Cookie{
    Name:     "jwtToken",
    Secure:   false,
    HttpOnly: true,
    Value:    tokenString,
    Expires:  expiryTime,
}
```

The problem is with Safari only.

Comment: @CeriseLimón this didn't work. What other information do you need?

Comment: @CeriseLimón the problem is with safari only every other browser is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other browsers, Safari does not set cookies on cross domain requests from XHR or fetch.  Serve the front end and back end from the same hOst.

Comment: Thank you @user11718744 your suggestion worked. I transferred the backend code to the same server on which frontend code was running. Thanks again :)